# linq-to-sql; handling a single returned value from ExecuteQuery

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I have a C# app that uses Linq-to-SQL to connect to a SQL Server 2008 database.

I need to get a single value from database through executing a query by means of `ExecuteQuery` function. `ExecuteQuery` returns `IEnumerable<>`, I'm trying to get the first item of the returned list using (`First()`, `FirstOrDefault()`, `Single()`, etc...)  but nothing works, always an `InvalidCastException` is thrown.

```
DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
<long> ll =  dc.ExecuteQuery<long>(@"SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('invoice_glass_lens')");
```

The exception is thrown even before using `.First()` or other methods and the list ll contains nothing. It seems that the problem is resulting from trying to assign a single value to `IEnumerable`, I just don't know what to do>

Comment: According to the documentation on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx, it looks like the return value is a `double` or `decimal`, not a `long`. Have you tried that?

Comment: And according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109.aspx, it looks like you may need to return an object with a property, not just one value.

Comment: Usually there is NO need for the ID if you use Linq-2-sql the way it is designed. WHat is the real purpose? You insert a new entity and need the id? In those cases just return the entity

Comment: Actually I need the ID before insertion because I have to display it for the user (as readonly) to know what number will the new added entity will take to. I'm using ID as readonly GUI element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `IDENT_CURRENT` returns a `NUMERIC(38,0)`, you need to use a `decimal` in .NET to handle the return value:

```
using (DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext()) 
{
   decimal? ll =  dc.ExecuteQuery<decimal>(@"SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('invoice_glass_lens')").FirstOrDefault;
}
```